# How to change text of button after pressing label in MDDropdownMenu in KivyMD?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I want to know - how to change text of the button in Kivy (and KivyMD) after pressing some label in the list after the opening MDDropdownMenu.

There is my Main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

def toast(text):
    from kivymd.toast.kivytoast import toast

    toast(text)

class MyScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.menu_items = [
                {
                    "viewclass": "MDMenuItem",
                    "text": "text%d" % i,
                    "callback": self.callback,
                }
                for i in range(1, 3)
            ]

    def change_variable(self, value):
        print("\nvalue=", value)
        self.VARIABLE = value
        print("\tself.VARIABLE=", self.VARIABLE)

    def callback(self, *args):
        toast(args[0])

class MainApp(App):
    title = "KivyMD MDDropdownMenu Demo"
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        return MyScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

And there is my Main.kv

```
#:import MDDropdownMenu kivymd.menus.MDDropdownMenu
#:import MDRaisedButton kivymd.button.MDRaisedButton

<MDMenuItem>:
    on_release: app.root.change_variable(self.text)

<MyScreen>:
    name: 'myscrn'
    MDRaisedButton:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 3 * dp(48), dp(48)
        text: 'MDButton'
        opposite_colors: True
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        on_release: MDDropdownMenu(items=root.menu_items, width_mult=4).open(self)
```

Sorry for bad English, and Thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Give an `id` to the main button, e.g. `id: mainbutton`
2. Update the main button's `text` in the `on_release` event of `MDMenuItem`
3. Optional: Replace `toast(args[0])` with `pass` in method `callback` (if you don't want to invoke `toast.py`)

## Snippets - kv file

```
<MDMenuItem>:
    on_release:
        app.root.ids.mainbutton.text = self.text
        app.root.change_variable(self.text)

<MyScreen>:
    name: 'myscrn'
    MDRaisedButton:
        id: mainbutton
        ...
```

## Output

[image: MDDropdownMenu - before selection]
[image: MDDropdownMenu - after selection]

Comment: Hey, you have answered my last question! Can you tell where did u get the real-working documentation of KivyMD or where have u seen those update features like updates of modules code of KivyMD?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no KivyMD programming guide but you can use [Kivy's Programming Guide](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/basic.html).

Comment: Oh, okay...thanks a lot for ur help! Maybe next time I will make a question about TimePicker in KivyMD. I hope I can make next things without ur help, but who knows...